# Return to original thread to display alert prompt

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm looking to understand some code that someone else wrote. I generally understand what is going on, but not exactly. The problem is that the code in question runs on another thread and handles an event on that second thread. However I need to present the user with an alert and if I fire the alert from the second thread it doesn't display, well of course, since the UI is running on the first thread. So how do I "switch" to the first thread handing off or marshaling my biz object that was retrieved by second thread, so the first thread can process it and display alert? I thought you would use a delegate in such a situation, but is the delegate still firing on the second thread?

Here is the code for the second thread:

```
public delegate void MessageReceivedEventHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs args);

public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    ...snip...
}

public class MSMQListenerService
{
 ...
  public event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived;
  ....

   public void Start()
    {
        ...
        //this is where we jump to a second thread as this method is IAsyncResult
        _queue.BeginReceive(); 
        ...
    }
   ....
 }
```

Code for the first thread:

```
....snip...

 x = new MSMQListenerService(@".\private$\abc");
 x.MessageReceived += x_MessageReceived;
 x.FormatterTypes = new Type[] { typeof(LoginStatusMessage) };
 x.Start();

...snip....

void x_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs args)
{
 //this handler is running on a different thread???
 //I'm OK with that just need to get the args back to the first thread
}
```

So I have posted the code that I thought would be relevant without overwhelming the post. So if something is missing please let me know and I'll definitely add it right away.

TIA
JB

Comment: Check info about `Dispatcher` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question: You need to invoke the call on the UI Thread.

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show("THIS WILL SHOW ON UI THREAD"); } ));
```

or instead of using lambda expression, you can use delegates:

```
private void DisplayMessage(string message) 
{ 
   ...
}

private delegate void SomeDelegateThatWillRunOnUIThread(string message);

...

this.BeginInvoke(new SomeDelegateThatWillRunOnUIThread(DisplayMessage), yourMessage);
```

Where `this` refers to the instance that is being ran on the UI thread.

I strongly recommend you read this tutorial to gain more insight
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke

Comment: Sooo umm I'm sure you'll get a good laugh out of this but I'm not sure how I get a handle to **this** (the instance the ui is running on). I mean I would execute the BeginInvoke delegateon the second thread no? Anyway I'm going through the tutorial now as I'm sure it will answer that question.

Comment: Alright I am confused. It worked but I'm still not sure. this.BeginInvoke is executed from the second thread...thus **this** is within the context of the second thread only. Fine so it send the msg to the msg pump and the pump hand off to the ui thread. Do I have that right? I'm not sure because you state "Where this refers to the instance that is being run on the UI thread."     ??????

Comment: The keyword **this** refers to the instance of the class that you are in, which means it's always in the thread that it was originally invoked in (in this case, UI thread). By calling **this.beginInvoke**, you are saying that you want to run the code in the thread of the instance of the class the method x_MessageReceived belongs to. Begininvoke is actually derived from control class so if you have any other instance of a control object (say another form), you can also call **NameOfYourControlObject.BeginInvoke** and it will run the code in that corresponding thread as well.

Comment: @user1278561 Lambda Expression is used there for simplifying your delegate declaration, so that you don't have to go through the trouble of declaring a handler function and a delegate See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) for more info.